# SP 2013 - Updating a multi-value lookup field via the REST API - Bad request

Tags: workflow, rest, multiple-values, http-400-bad-request

I am trying to update a multi-value lookup field via the REST Api in a workflow.
It works great in Fiddler. However, when I run the workflow I get a 400 bad request error. When I log everything in the Workflow, it looks correct.

My URL:
https://sites.generic/sites/PSA/projecttracker/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('Doc%20Central')/items(42)

Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose

{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Data.ListItem"},"LanguagesId":{"results":[3,15,35]}}

The content lines I have logged straight from the workflow. Visually it looks correct. I am guessing that SP is adding something to break it.

Comment: There are some configurations for calling REST API from workflow. Did you do that?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your workflow? We can only guess without knowing the issue as this seems to be very generic.